# ffmpeg detect when a mp3 remote audio changes

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm downloading via `ffmpeg` a mp3 hosted on some data source:

```
function (fpath, opath, sampleRate) {
      var self = this;

      // defaults
      sampleRate = sampleRate || '44100';
      var loglevel = self.logger.isDebug() ? 'debug' : 'warning';
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const args = [
          '-y',
          '-loglevel', loglevel,
          '-i', fpath,
          '-ar', sampleRate,
          '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le',
          opath
        ];
        const opts = {
          cwd: self._options.tempDir
        };
        cp.spawn('ffmpeg', args, opts)
          .on('message', msg => self.logger.info(msg))
          .on('error', reject)
          .on('close', resolve);
      });
    }
```

The data source, slightly changes this audio file from time to time. Is there a way for `ffmpeg` - for a given url - to check if that audio file has changed **without** downloading the whole file?

I've trying using `curl -I` as basic check, but I'm not sure it's the right approach for mp3 audio files that will exist anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffprobe -print_format json URL`;
adding `-show_entries`  you can pick only desidered infos, what you think is appropriate to decide if there is a change